# jquery validation error Expected identifier, string, or number

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a little problem with jquery validation. In IE 6 and maybee in IE 7 i got an error message: Expected identifier....

I minimised my code and it seems, if i cut out the following part, then everything is works fine. 
Whats the problem?

I dont really understand where is the extra comma, so i decided i paste the hole validate script. Please take a look at my code.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zőöüóúéáűí ]+$/i.test(value);
}, "... betűket használjon");   

$("#test").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 40,
                lettersonly: true
        },
        addr: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 15,
                maxlength: 80


        },
        phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
            email: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                email: true      
        },
        count: {
        required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
        nettoj: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
        nettoj2: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
        mini: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
        mini2: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
        adosj: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
        amini: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
        stil: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
        tcount: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 20,
                number: true         
        },
        city: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 60,
                lettersonly: true        
        },


    },
    messages: {
        name: {
                required: "... !",
                minlength: "Minimum 5 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 40 "
        },
        addr: {
                required: "... ",
                minlength: "Minimum 15 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 80 "
        },
        phone: {
                required: "... ",
                minlength: "Minimum 8 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                number: "... "

        },

        email: {
                required: "... e-mail ",
                minlength: "Minimum 5 ",
                email: "..."

        },
        count: {
                required: "... ",
                minlength: "Minimum 3 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                                number: "... "

        },
            nettoj: {
                minlength: "Minimum 2 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                                number: "... "

        },
            nettoj2: {
                minlength: "Minimum 2 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                                number: "... "

        },
                mini: {
                minlength: "Minimum 2 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                                number: "... "

        },
                mini2: {
                minlength: "Minimum 2 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                                number: "... "

        },
                adosj: {
                minlength: "Minimum 2 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                                number: "... "

        },
                amini: {
                minlength: "Minimum 2 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
            number: "... "

        },
                stil: {
                minlength: "Minimum 2 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                                number: "... "

        },
                tcount: {
                minlength: "Minimum 2 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                                number: "... "

        },
                city: {
                minlength: "Minimum 3 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 80 "
        },

    },



   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you appended an extra comma to your object literal property, get rid of it

```
object = {
    property1: 23,
    property2: 14,
    property3: 42 //The answer, also, no comma after the 42, as it's the last
}                 //property of the object, if you have a comma here, then the
                  //javascript engine is expecting another member item to the
                  //object, and get's really peeved if you don't add it.
```

The reason minimizing the code worked was because it was really nice and got rid of those nasty extra commas which were annoying your javascript engine.

**Edit**

You *still* have extra commas in you new code in between nesting levels

```
    city: {                    //Look, it's the last member of an object
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 60,
            lettersonly: true        
    }, //<-- WHAT IS THAT COMMA DOING THERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

/*At this point, parser is like, wtf, where's the next member?*/},
```

Comment: please take a look at my code, i pasted the hole script 'coz i dont really find the extra comma...thank you

Comment: @hollan you might want to look again. You have 3 or 4 extra commas. (one at the end of each property list)

Comment: ehh..you mess me up...so i have to do this?   stil: {
                minlength: "Minimum 2 ",
                maxlength: "Maximum 20 ",
                                number: "... "

        }, // <<<--- that is the extra comma?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last `,` at this piece of code.

### old

```
addr: {
    required: "...",
    minlength: "...",
    maxlength: "..."
},
```

### new

```
addr: {
    required: "...",
    minlength: "...",
    maxlength: "..."
}
```

Comment: please take a look at my code, i pasted the hole script 'coz i dont really find the extra comma...thank you